# Automatically migrate Azure Logic workflow using Azure devops pipeline to empty logicapp

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

In my Azure portal I have created one empty logic app in East US region.
And I created one sample logicapp workflow which contains http request trigger and initialize variable action.Then download this as json file and deleted this logicapp.
Now my requirement is in azure git repo I have to use this workflow json file as source and then using Azure devops pipeline need to deploy to that empty logicapp.  After successful deploy in azure portal the empty logicapp should have this workflow.
In my azure devops I created git repo with the name Demo repo and uploaded sample workflow json file.
After this I am facing issue like how to configure pipeline to achieve my requirement.

What I tried from my end,

Created empty logicapp region,
East US

Created Azure DevOps using,
Agile process and created
Demo Repo and uploaded sample workflow. Json.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> After this I am facing issue like how to configure pipeline to achieve my requirement.

In order to Deploy your Logic app files in Azure Portal, You can Use ARM Template Deployment Task in your Release pipeline and select your LogicApp.json file which has your Logic app workflow and LogicApp.parameters.json file which has your Logic app parameters like below:-

[image]

Select your LogicApp.json and LogicApp.parameters.json file by clicking on ... 3 dots and correct path to your repository. And In override parameter write the name of your existing Logic app and its location in the value like below:-

**Override Template parameter:-**

```
-logicAppName valleyLA87 -logicAppLocation australiaeast
```

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Updated:-

**My Azure Repository:-**

[image]

***I have selected the above LogicApp.json from my Repository in my template section of Release pipeline ARM Template Deployment Task and LogicApp.parameters.json in my Template parameter section.***

I recommend using Release pipeline and not CI Build pipeline But you can make use of  below YAML code in your build pipeline too -

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'SID subscription(xxxxx6e97cb2a7)'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxxx-e2b6e97cb2a7'
    resourceGroupName: siliconrg54
    location: 'Australia East'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_AzureResourceGroup5/AzureResourceGroup5/LogicApp.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_AzureResourceGroup5/AzureResourceGroup5/LogicApp.parameters.json'
    overrideParameters: '-logicAppName valleyLA87 -logicAppLocation australiaeast'
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show your Azure git repo and CI pipeline.

Comment: @KarmileS Check my updated answer with my repository and I recommend using Release pipeline rather than build

Comment: Refer this youtube video for more details and clarity- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPq2ifYCAkE&t=1055s

Comment: thank you actually i already tried your approach but i am getting the error as shown in image. could you please check that and help me where i am doing wrong .

Comment: could you please also show me your logicapp.json and logicappparameter.json how it looks?

Comment: You are not passing the parameters that are null in your LogicApp.parameters.json in the Override Template parameters section like here-  https://i.imgur.com/jN5XH1P.png thus its missing one parameter, If you can show me your LogicApp.parameters.json it would be good? Also make sure to add LogicAppLocation in tbhis format- australiaeast

Comment: added images please check and let me know what changes do i need?

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai . It works fine but whenever i am uploading new workflow in repo it asking for release pipeline config changes. is there any way to automatic this process like every time i push sample workflow in repo it needs to be triggered and create that new workflow in destination logicapp. Could you please hlep

Comment: @KarmileS Try enabling this option - https://i.imgur.com/ONR0jcR.png to enable continous deployment once code changes are done in your repository

Comment: i don't want to edit the code in the same file. I want to upload new files in repo and don't want to change every time template configuration. I hope you understand

Comment: SiddheshDesai and sorry to say this when i tried same workflow to add in empty standard logicapp it,s creating consumption logicapp with the same name of standard instead of creating workflow in existing standard lap. could you please check on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255561/discussion-between-karmile-s-and-siddheshdesai).

Comment: please give my reply . Your approach is not working for standard logicapp. Instead of creating workflow in my standard logicapp it is creating consumption logicapp with the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77263543/automatically-create-different-workflows-in-standard-logicapp-using-azure-devops

Comment: please reply me asap i am waiting from yesterday for your response.

Comment: @KarmileS I am reworking with your scenario, Allow me sometime

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai any luck please?

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai as you said you are reworking on it are you able to figure it out or not. Please respond.

Comment: What you can try is export the existing Logic App resource as ARM template and then use it in your release pipeline with Incremental mode -https://i.imgur.com/wgM4XwR.png Incremental mode will keep the existing resource as it is and will deploy new settings or any new resource you add in your template apart from the existing parameters

Comment: You need to reference the existing resource in your ARM template as Release pipeline will create new resource if the existing resource is not referenced in the ARM template

Comment: i am already using Incremental mode. please check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77263543/automatically-create-different-workflows-in-standard-logicapp-using-azure-devops
This is what i am saying it's not working for standard logicapp . Using your approach it is creating consumption. Please check this cleraly and If your approach really working for standard please show me that in images.

Comment: "kind": "Standard"
Can you set this in your template.json? I do not see any SKU set to concumption or Standard in your template.json?

Comment: yeah now you are on track. That's what i am saying Whatever template.json i am using it's not refering to standard kind and sku so that's what i am asking can you please do changes in my template.json it works for standard. If possible you can provide here or else you can add that in that quesion also i will accept both your answers then

Comment: could you please do it the one who is giving answer there is wrong so you can give it there or you can correct that tempalte.json and add it in your solution here. i will accept it. Thank you

Comment: can you please respond?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255595/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-karmile-s).