# Automatic deployment of multiple workflows to empty standard logicapp using azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Here as you can see i have 2 sample different workflows in my repo.
[image: image.png]
In this release pipeline i am using arm template deploy and i am able to add this sample workflow configuration
[image: image.png]

after release i am able to see this sample workflow in my destination empty consumption logic app. But what if i have multiple sample workflows in my repo, am i need to go to every time release pipeline and do i need to change every time this template configuration.
Is there any way to automatic this like, if i upload multiple different workflows in git repo then pipeline automatically trigger and create those multiple workflows in single empty standard logic app.

1. Is this possible automatically create different workflows to single empty consumption logic app,  whenever I uploaded different multiple workflows to git repo with out changing template configuration every time.

2.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77250036/automatically-migrate-azure-logic-workflow-using-azure-devops-pipeline-to-empty
this will work for consumption what if my destination empty logic app is standard and i want to add multiple workflows to this empty standard logicapp.What changes do i need in my git repo file and pipeline

As shown in images whenever i uploaded new workflows to git repo it asking for template configuartion in release pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no method can automatically update the release configuration for the ARM templates deployment.

When we use the ARM template deployment task in Release Pipeline, the path of the workflow.json file used needs to be set manually in advance, and it cannot automatically obtain the newly added workflow file.

At the same time, the ARM template deployment task can only deploy one workflow json file each time it is run.

Therefore, when you upload multiple workflow files, you need to manually change the Release Pipeline configuration before you can successfully deploy.

For more detailed information, you can refer to this doc about [Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template Deployment Task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md)

Comment: Thank you . Then for sure there will be other approach to work with different workflows with different names right. Can you please let me know any possible ways are there to get this done.

Comment: @KarmileS Can you share more details about the requirement: work with different workflows with different names? Then I can help you find the possible ways.

Comment: sure. Suppose i have one workflow json with the name demo1 contains http trigger and intialize variable action and i have another workflow json with the name demo2 contains blob trigger and compose action . so i want this demo1 and demo 2 will appear in my standard logicapp for eg Demo-standard -lap. In this way if i have multiple workflows with diiferent names demo1,demo2 etc in my azure git repo i have these workflows in my standard logicapp

Comment: Currently, when you deploy the demo1 and demo2, they are all in one standard logic app or they  are in different logic apps? Please help me confirm it

Comment: same standard logic app

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT Any luck?

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT could you please respond and give me update on my issue.

Comment: can you please respond?

Comment: From your requirement, it is related to how to set the workflow template itself of the logic app. I am not so familiar with this scope. I can only give you some advice from the perspective of Azure DevOps.

Comment: ok at least give me some approach to automate multiple workflows . How we can go every time to ARM template task and change there template settings. There will be possible way to automate this